# My SQL Echo Matching Query(s)

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to print all matching rows where the matching `Album` or `Artist` is matched. I have the code here but something is wrong. I've tried researching it but cant find anything distinct. I think that I am on the right track.

This isn't a duplicate question. Its not the quotes that are the problem because even when I removed them and changed the name it still does not work.

```
<form>
<h3>Please either search by Artist or Album:</h3>
    Artist: <input type="text" name="artist"><br /><br />
    Album: <input type="text" name="album"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search Database" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die(mysql_error());    
        mysql_select_db('music') or die("cannot select DB");

        if(!empty($_POST['artist'])) {
            $name = $_POST['artist'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'artists' WHERE 'artists name' =".$name;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Album'] . ':' . $row['Artist Name'] . '<br />';
            }
        } else if(!empty($_POST['album'])) {
            $name = $_POST['album'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'albums' WHERE 'Album' =".$name;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Artists'] . ':' . $row['Album'] . '<br />';
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>Please ente a search query</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use backticks to quote table and column names, not single quotes. Or don't quote them at all -- you only have to quote names if they contain special characters or are reserved words.

Comment: @th3r1singking also is 'artists name' a valid column name? it contains a space

Comment: @Arzgethalm yes it is a valid column name, should i remove the space?

Comment: you will encounter some problems with it later on. so you can replace that with underscore _

Comment: @Arzgethalm You can use any character you want in a column name, you just have to quote it with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks, not quotes, to escape table and column names that contain special characters. Quotes are for making literal strings.

Another problem is that the strings you're comparing to in the WHERE clause need to be put in quotes. And you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection (it would be better if you upgraded to `PDO` or `mysqli` and used prepared statements).

You need to use `<form method="post">` so that `$_POST` will be filled in with the form fields, or use `$_GET` to get the form fields. You could instead use `$_REQUEST`, which will work with either type of form.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die(mysql_error());    
        mysql_select_db('music') or die("cannot select DB");

        if(!empty($_POST['artist'])) {
            $name = $_POST['artist'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE `artist name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Album'] . ':' . $row['Artist Name'] . '<br />';
            }
        } else if(!empty($_POST['album'])) {
            $name = $_POST['album'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `albums` WHERE `Album` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Artists'] . ':' . $row['Album'] . '<br />';
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>Please ente a search query</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not resolve the issue. It's not a quotes or names issue

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause you have the column name `artists name`, but you print `$row['Artist Name']`. Is there an `s` at the end of `Artist` or not? Also, make sure you get the capitalization correct, PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: No that didnt work either

Comment: See my additional change. You didn't quote the names that you were comparing with.

Comment: It was that I didnt include the post method in the form.